# how to delete record on database using breezejs and web api 2?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

I want to delete record on database using breeze js and web api 2
this is my code :

```
materialAdmin
    .controller('schProgCtrl', function ($scope, breeze, $filter, $sce, ngTableParams, serviceUrl, schServiceName) {
        var serviceName = serviceUrl + schServiceName; // route to the Web Api controller
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
        $scope.getAll = function (query) {
            var eq = breeze.EntityQuery;
            var query = new eq(query)
            return manager.executeQuery(query);
        };

        $scope.update = function (w) {
            if(!w.Id){
                var type = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('MD_ScholarshipProgram');
                var newItem = type.createEntity(w);
                manager.addEntity(newItem);
            }
            if (manager.hasChanges()) {
                manager.saveChanges()
                    .then(function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        alerts('Oops!!! Data tidak ter-update ke server.');
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                    .finally(function () {
                        w.$edit = false;
                    });
            } else {
                alert("Nothing to save");
                w.$edit = false;
            }
        };
        $scope.addNew = function() {
            $scope.datatable.data.unshift({
                Name :'',
                Code : '',
                $edit : true
            });
        };
        $scope.delete = function (w) {
            console.log(w.entityAspect);
            w.entityAspect.setDeleted();
            manager.saveChanges();
        };
        $scope.datatable = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10
            },
            {
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    $scope.getAll({
                        from: "Program",
                        orderBy : ['Code asc'],
                        skip : ((params.page() -1) * params.count()),
                        take : params.count(),
                        inlineCount:true
                    })
                        .then(function (res) {
                            console.log(res);
                            params.total(res.inlineCount); 
                            var data = res.results;
                            $defer.resolve(data);

                        });

                }
            });

    });
```

I using `ngTable`.

But i get an error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDeleted' of undefined`

may be the way i delete is wrong, how properly delete record using breeze js?

Comment: Is `w` a breeze entity?  If so, it would have an `entityAspect`.

Comment: I think `w` is not breeze entity as steve said, please check object first and directly bind breeze list/object to your ui and than do CRUD operation on it.